# ngModel checkbox not shown as selected

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I'm having some trouble getting a checkbox to display the correct state (checked/unchecked) of my model. I have the following in my controller:

```
app.controller('PhotosCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.editPhotos = {
        token: $scope.token,
        idArray: $scope.idArray
    };
}]);
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="editPhotosForm" ng-submit="submit(editPhotos);" multipart="true" novalidate>
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="editPhotos.token" ng-init="editPhotos.token='<%= form_authenticity_token %>'">
    <div class="results-label"><b>{{total_count}}</b> <span ng-if="total_count == 1">Photo</span><span ng-if="total_count != 1">Photos</span> Found</div>
    <div>
        <div class="col">
            <a ng-repeat="r in results" class="card result-link">
                <div class="content result">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="idArray[r.id]">
                    </div>

                    <div class="image-container" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + r.image_url + ')'}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

On my repeater element, I call `ng-init="idArray[r.id] = 'false'"` to initialize a key `r.id = 'false'` for each item in `r`. I don't know if I need to do this or not. I've tried the code without it and it makes no difference. I've also tried using `ng-value-true` and `ng-value-false` but those don't seem to be working for me.

Most of the other posts I've seen on this issue deal with simple variables (e.g. `$scope.someVar = true` rather than more complex structures like a hash.

Here is the structure of `idArray`:

```
$scope.idArray = {1290: "false", 1291: "true", 1292: "true", 1293: "false", 1294: "false", 1414: "false"};
```

This is generated by the `ng-init` in my repeater, since the ids of the photos can't be known beforehand.

Here is what `results` looks like:

```
{
    id: 1290,
    company_id: null,
    image_url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/photos/images/000/001/290/original/214.JPG?1432217895"
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? There is no `results` array to iterate on, son I don't see how you can see any checkbox. And you're confusing the string `'false'` with the boolean `false`.

Comment: In my repeater, I initialize the hash key to `'false'` instead of `false` because the values for `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` are always strings. The `results` array is defined on `$scope` from an AJAX call, which returns a list of photos from the database. I'll add the structure of `idArray` to my question above for reference.

Comment: While reading my answer, I see that there might be an issue with my answer depending of the data structure of your object `result`. Can you post a sample?

Comment: I just appended a snippet to my question.

Comment: Your result is an array of this object?

Comment: `results` is an array of hashes. Each hash looks like the one in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the following

```
    ng-init="idArray[r.id] = 'false'"
```

You're assigning the string value `'false'` into your object.

Can't you deal with that inside your controller?

```
$scope.idArray = {};
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.results.length; ++i){
    $scope.idArray[$scope.results[i].id] = (i%2 == 0);
}
```

And removing the `ng-init=""` (which is, according to Angular doc, a bad practice https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit ).

Another thing was the anchor element that was wrapping the checkbox element. This lead to the click event that was not triggered on the checkbox, but only on the anchor.

```
    <div class="col">
        <div ng-repeat="r in results" class="card result-link">
            <div class="content result">
                <div class="caption">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="idArray[r.id]">
                </div>

                <div class="image-container" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + r.image_url + ')'}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/patxy/wak7pwwp/

Comment: So I deleted the `ng-init` from my repeater and now I just have `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="idArray[r.id]">`. This generates a hash that looks like `{1291: true}`, but the checkbox still doesn't show the correct state. It is always unchecked.

Comment: I made a small change `ng-model="$parent.idArray[r.id]"`. Can you test it? ng-repeat creates a new scope for each element. So your ng-model is in a child scope.

Comment: No luck with `$parent.idArray[r.id]`. I also tried `$parent.editPhotos.idArray[r.id]` without success. If I `console.log($scope.idArray)` I get the correct data structure, so checking the box is doing something.

Comment: I've noticed that when I click the checkbox, a key `id: true` is added to `idArray`. The checkbox still appears unchecked. If I click it again, I expect the key to be deleted from the array, or the value to change. Neither occurs.

Comment: I spotted my error by testing in a fiddle. It was a stupid on into the for loop. Also, I let a working sample in a fiddle.

Comment: Adding the `for` loop generates a hash key in `idArray` for each element, but that still doesn't solve the issue, which is that the checkboxes always appear unchecked, even if I check them. Now if I set them all to `true` in the `for` loop, they all appear checked, but I can't uncheck any of them.

Comment: Even on your fiddle, the checkbox state is immutable.

Comment: Your checkbox was in an anchor. Maybe this is the cause of this issue. Not every browser reacts the same when you do that. Can you try this updated version? (new fiddle also)

Comment: Yes, that must be the cause. It's working now. Thanks! Can you edit your answer and I'll check it? Hopefully that will help someone else.